# Why are my entry dates displaying incorrectly in Safari?

Tags: date, variable, bug

I'm not sure what could be causing this.

Dates are displaying incorrectly in Safari on my site. They are displaying as 1 day before the actual date that is set in the CP. I've never seen this and have absolutely no clue how to fix. All my searches have come up nothing.

For Ex:
Entry Date in CP: 1/25/12

Chrome displays: 1/25/12

Safari displays: 1/24/12

Comment: What are your timezone settings? Are you logged in as the same member in all browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your site's and user profile's localization settings. It's very likely that you're viewing the site in Safari while logged in as a user with a locale that differs from the locale configured for the site.

Documentation: [Site Localization Settings](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/localization_settings.html), [Enabling/disabling User-specific Localization](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/membership_preferences.html#allow-members-to-set-their-own-localization-preferences)

Comment: it was the 'Daylight Saving Time' set to 'No' that triggered the wrong dates.

Comment: Ah--I was going to mention DST, but figured since you were seeing the difference of a full day that it was more likely the broader localization settings. Either way, I'm glad that you found your answer!